# Reopening Which patches do I need to apply on Magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: discussion, support

First of all, i ***would like say sorry*** for  put this question  [Which patches do I need to apply on Magento 1.7.0.2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84686/which-patches-do-i-need-to-apply-on-magento-1-7-0-2) as duplicate of my question
[what are the sequence of mutliple patches apply on magento 1.7.0.2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/79320/sequence-of-mutliple-patches-appply-for-magento-1-7-0-2).

Both the question asked for different points of view.

@Alex, want know about ***list of patches*** which are used for magento 1.7.0.2

I was asking about ***sequence of those patches which are applied  on magento 1.7.0.2. and why it show error during the patch appling***.

**So , if any one will agree with me then please put their reopen vote**